# Mysql how to use IN with IF in where clause?

Tags: mysql

I want to have something like this:

```
SELECT
  p.name_en AS 'province_$lang',
  p.province_code AS 'province_code_$lang',
  COUNT(u.id) AS 'total_$lang',
  COUNT(u.id) AS total
FROM applications AS a 
LEFT JOIN users AS u on u.id = a.user_id 
LEFT JOIN provinces AS p on p.province_code = u.province_code
WHERE a.progress_status IN (0,1,2,3) AND IF( a.progress_status = 2,a.denial_type ,1) IN IF(a.`progress_status` = 2,(1,2,3),1)
GROUP BY u.province_code
```

Suppose I have two field in table one of them is `progress_status` that can has one of these `0,1,2, or 3` value, and another field `denial_type` that can take `1,2, or 3`, but `denial_type` only can take one of those value when `progress_status` is 2.
so i want to check if `progress_status` is `IN` 0,1,2,3 and for those records that its `progress_status` is 2 then its `denial_type` should be `IN` 1,2,3

Comment: Is it a `select query`. Also can you show your entire query?

Comment: @MilanGupta I have update my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
p.name_en AS 'province_$lang',
p.province_code AS 'province_code_$lang',
COUNT(u.id) AS 'total_$lang',
COUNT(u.id) AS total
FROM applications AS a 
LEFT JOIN users AS u on u.id = a.user_id 
LEFT JOIN provinces AS p on p.province_code = u.province_code
WHERE a.progress_status IN (0,1,2,3) AND   
IF( a.progress_status = 2,  
(select denial_type from applications where denial_type IN (1,2,3)) ,1) 
GROUP BY u.province_code
```

Using `subquery` in `IF` condition to select only those `denial_type` whose value is `IN (1,2,3)` might solve your problem.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Subquery return more than one row.

Comment: Try using `LIMIT`: `select denial_type from applications where denial_type IN (1,2,3) LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0):

Post aggregate filtering should do the trick

```
SELECT
  p.name_en AS 'province_$lang',
  p.province_code AS 'province_code_$lang',
  COUNT(u.id) AS 'total_$lang',
  COUNT(u.id) AS total
FROM applications AS a 
LEFT JOIN users AS u on u.id = a.user_id 
LEFT JOIN provinces AS p on p.province_code = u.province_code
GROUP BY u.province_code
HAVING SUM(a.progress_status IN (0,1,2,3))>0
AND SUM(a.progress_status = 2 AND a.denial_type IN(1,2,3))>0
```